# updating label text in kivy on load

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm brand new to kivy, and trying to build small OSD for my raspberry.

My .kv file looks like this:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text_size: self.size
        text: 'OSD'
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'top'
        size_hint: 1, .3
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text_size: self.size
            text: 'Total entries in DB: '
            font_size: 30
            bold: False
            halign:  'left'
            size_hint: 1, .1
        Label:
            id: total_db
            text_size: self.size
            text: '366 000 '
            font_size: 30
            bold: True
            color: 0, 1, 0, 1
            halign:  'center'
            size_hint: 1, .1
        Label:
            text_size: self.size
            text: 'Info 1: '
            font_size: 30
            bold: False
            halign: 'left'
            size_hint: 1, .1
        Label:
            id: marked_update
            text_size: self.size
            text: '1328 '
            color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            font_size: 30
            bold: True
            halign:  'center'
            size_hint: 1, .1
    Label:
        text_size: self.size
        text: 'Activity'
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'top'
        size_hint: 1, .3
    Label:
        text: ''
        font_size: 10
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'top'
        size_hint: 1, .08

    GridLayout:
        cols: 4
        Button:
            text: 'DS 01'
            font_size: 25
            background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Button:
            text: 'DS 02'
            font_size: 25
            background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
        Button:
            text: 'DS 03'
            font_size: 25
            background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
        Button:
            text: 'DS 04'
            font_size: 25
            background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
```

This produce the look I want. I wan to periodically update the two labels texts with IDs with values I extract later on... but I can't even update them from python which looks like this:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

class BoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_txt, 0)

    def update_txt(self, *args):
        self.label.ids.marked_update.txt='updated from python'

class osdApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'OSD'
        return BoxLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    osdApp().run()
```

I was thinking to start clock that calls the update_txt function and that could change the value, but I keep getting error that ids does not exists... and so on, I'm bread new to object oriented programming and I can't figure this simple thing out

Comment: the indentation in the .kv is important, and according to what I see this is not appropriate, you could correct it.

Comment: @eyllanesc true, the forum formated it when I pasted it it, I have edited it reflect my file... but that might not be the issue, it would not start if indentation was wrong...

Comment: I understand you, but that minor problem could make us assume that this is the problem, verify that the code is correct. :D

Comment: An error in your code is that the class that inherits from a class should not be called the same as the class it inherits: `class BoxLayout(BoxLayout):
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations:

- As comments @eyllanesc, you shouldn't name your subclasses  as the class that it inherits.
- `self.label.ids.marked_update.txt` is incorrect. It should be `self.ids.marked_update.text`.
- Declare your root widget as a kv rule.

Your code could be:

- **main.py**

  ```
  import kivy
  kivy.require('1.10.0')

  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
  from kivy.clock import Clock


  class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
          Clock.schedule_once(self.update_txt, 0.1)

      def update_txt(self, *args):
          self.ids.marked_update.text = 'updated from python'


  class OsdApp(App):
      def build(self):
          self.title = 'OSD'
          return RootWidget()


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      OsdApp().run()
  ```
- **osd.kv:**

  ```
  <RootWidget>:
      orientation: 'vertical'
      Label:
          text_size: self.size
          text: 'OSD'
          font_size: 50
          bold: True
          halign: 'center'
          valign: 'top'
          size_hint: 1, .3
      GridLayout:
          cols: 2
          Label:
              text_size: self.size
              text: 'Total entries in DB: '
              font_size: 30
              bold: False
              halign:  'left'
              size_hint: 1, .1
          Label:
              id: total_db
              text_size: self.size
              text: '366 000 '
              font_size: 30
              bold: True
              color: 0, 1, 0, 1
              halign:  'center'
              size_hint: 1, .1
          Label:
              text_size: self.size
              text: 'Info 1: '
              font_size: 30
              bold: False
              halign: 'left'
              size_hint: 1, .1
          Label:
              id: marked_update
              text_size: self.size
              text: '1328 '
              color: 1, 0, 0, 1
              font_size: 30
              bold: True
              halign:  'center'
              size_hint: 1, .1
      Label:
          text_size: self.size
          text: 'Activity'
          font_size: 50
          bold: True
          halign: 'center'
          valign: 'top'
          size_hint: 1, .3
      Label:
          text: ''
          font_size: 10
          halign: 'center'
          valign: 'top'
          size_hint: 1, .08

      GridLayout:
          cols: 4
          Button:
              text: 'DS 01'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
          Button:
              text: 'DS 02'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
          Button:
              text: 'DS 03'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
          Button:
              text: 'DS 04'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
  ```

However, I recommend using kivy properties instead of ids:

- **main.py**:

  ```
  import kivy
  kivy.require('1.10.0')

  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
  from kivy.properties import StringProperty


  class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
      marked_text = StringProperty()

      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
          self.update_txt()

      def update_txt(self, *args):
          self.marked_text ='updated from python'


  class OsdApp(App):
      def build(self):
          self.title = 'OSD'
          return RootWidget()


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      OsdApp().run()
  ```
- **osd.kv:**

  ```
  <RootWidget>:
      id: root_layout
      orientation: 'vertical'
      marked_text: '1328 '

      Label:
          text_size: self.size
          text: 'OSD'
          font_size: 50
          bold: True
          halign: 'center'
          valign: 'top'
          size_hint: 1, .3
      GridLayout:
          cols: 2
          Label:
              text_size: self.size
              text: 'Total entries in DB: '
              font_size: 30
              bold: False
              halign:  'left'
              size_hint: 1, .1
          Label:
              id: total_db
              text_size: self.size
              text: '366 000 '
              font_size: 30
              bold: True
              color: 0, 1, 0, 1
              halign:  'center'
              size_hint: 1, .1
          Label:
              text_size: self.size
              text: 'Info 1: '
              font_size: 30
              bold: False
              halign: 'left'
              size_hint: 1, .1
          Label:
              id: marked_update
              text_size: self.size
              text: root_layout.marked_text
              color: 1, 0, 0, 1
              font_size: 30
              bold: True
              halign:  'center'
              size_hint: 1, .1
      Label:
          text_size: self.size
          text: 'Activity'
          font_size: 50
          bold: True
          halign: 'center'
          valign: 'top'
          size_hint: 1, .3
      Label:
          text: ''
          font_size: 10
          halign: 'center'
          valign: 'top'
          size_hint: 1, .08

      GridLayout:
          cols: 4
          Button:
              text: 'DS 01'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
          Button:
              text: 'DS 02'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
          Button:
              text: 'DS 03'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
          Button:
              text: 'DS 04'
              font_size: 25
              background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
  ```

Comment: Thank you ! also I did not notice that its self.ids.marked_update.text and NOT self.ids.marked_update.txt as I had... :D  any particular reason not to use ids ? ( i'm so happy its finally working, and can continue experimenting, it was driving me nuts :D )

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds their way to this question in search of an on_load event in kivy, I have found a solution.
The App class in kivy provides a member function on_start(self), which is called once the app is done building and loading. We simply need to add the functions we want to call after the app is done loading in its body.
Ex:

```html
class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    ...
  def on_start(self):
    super().on_start(self)
    my_f()
    update_texts()
```